# Listing all files in current directory to a String in C

Tags: c, string, stdout

Ok so I'm trying to list all the files of the current directory directory to a String in C.
The files in the current directory are:

myftpclient.c , myftpclient.o, myftpserver.c, myftpserver.o

```
char * list(void) 
{
    DIR *dp; // directory var
    struct dirent *ep;
    char str[256] ;
    int n = 0 ;
    dp = opendir ("./");
    if (dp != NULL)
    {
        while ((ep = readdir (dp)))
        {
            int curLen = strlen((ep->d_name)) ;
            strncat(str, (ep->d_name), curLen) ;
            strncat(str, "\n", 1) ;
            n += curLen + 1 ;
        }
        str[n] = '\0' ;
        (void) closedir (dp);
    }
    else
        perror ("Couldn't open the directory");

    return str ;
}
```

This is my call to it:

```
char * str = malloc(256) ;
str = list() ;
```

My output when I print the string is:
`B0`

Which is not even close to correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the other program in? like c,bash,etc? and how does it not work at all, with the other program what?

Comment: You must consider that this is not a code review service. Please **edit your question** to state what you used as input (what is in the directory), what you got as output and what you think is the issue might be. If you help people help you then you're likely to get some good answer. In fact a simple wrapper around the function doing this might make is really easy for someone including yourself to see what is happening.

Comment: I edited my question to make it much more clear. The other program is a C program as well, but I should have never mentioned it, it is irrelevant, I am testing the results within this very program.

Comment: maybe pipe to the other program, huh so you get it to the other program or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the following problems in your code.

1. You are creating an array of `char` to hold only `256` characters. You will run into out of bounds memory access when the number of characters required to hold names of the directory entries and the newline character exceed `256`.
2. You are returning a pointer to an array defined in the local scope. The array will be invalid once you return from the function.
3. You can use `strcat` instead of `strncat`. `strncat` is useful only when you want to append less than the number of characters being held at the source.

You can fix those issues by:

1. Using `malloc` to allocate memory for `str`.
2. Using `realloc` to increase the allocated memory for each directory entry.
3. Make sure you `free` the memory returned from `list()` in the calling function.

Here's a version that should work.

```
char * list(void) 
{
    DIR *dp; // directory var
    struct dirent *ep;
    char* str = malloc(1);
    int n = 0 ;
    str[0] = '\0';
    dp = opendir ("./");
    if (dp != NULL)
    {
        while ((ep = readdir (dp)))
        {
            int curLen = strlen((ep->d_name)) ;
            n += curLen + 2 ; // One of the terminating null and the
                              // other for the newline.
            str = realloc(str, n);
            strcat(str, (ep->d_name)) ;
            strcat(str, "\n") ;
        }
        (void) closedir (dp);
    }
    else
        perror ("Couldn't open the directory");

    return str;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly it! Thanks for the very detailed explanation of the working version.